# Problem with Notification panel icon(top right icon),android 4.4.4 ?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I own a Android One phone launched last year,Micromax AQ4501 running android 4.4.4, from last week i having this problem where the icon on the notification bar (which has a face )which when touched switches and takes one to setting panel with bluetooth ,brightness ,battery,wifi etc,keeps shifting to the right side such that only half of it is visible and the rest goes beyond the scope of the display,it sometimes gets back to normal automatically  ,other times requires a reboot and one time it completely disappeared and i had to do two finger pull down to bring the setting page.
How can this problem be resolved ??? Is their a virus ??
[image]
in the first image the icon has completely disappeared

[image]
in the second image the icon has shifted to the right

[image]THE third image shows the default location of the icon.
Please help..

Comment: Do you have your device rooted? Are you using xposed framework?